# Website migration + redesign = 20k 404 error links and bad SEO

Tags: wordpress, seo, http-status-code-404, google-crawlers

I recently moved my website from one host to another, and the Joomla content got replaced by a WordPress website. But now Google search console is telling me that all the previous links from the Joomla website are missing, which amounts to over 20K crawl errors, and i lost all my SEO (website is gone from first result).

What can I do? I have been looking all over the Internet but I can't create a redirection for every missing link, is there an easy way to fix this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply permanently redirect all 404 results to your homepage - there are several Wordpress plugins which do this for you (like this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/404-to-301/). This way you'll keep all the links that point to the now non-existent pages.

The better option (and the more time-consuming one) is to check where the 404 errors are pointing and redirect them to the appropriate page (not simply your homepage). This is only worth doing for the pages that had a decent rank before the migration.

Have in mind that even after you fix the errors it will take some time until you restore your search engine rank.

Comment: I think it only works for WordPress 404 pages, because the missing pages from the previous Joomla showed up again in Google Search Console. Is it because I didn't wait enough, or is  there a way to fix that ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean - all non-existent pages will return a 404 error. If a page returned 404 before the wordpress migration it will still do so. You can go through the URLs that return 404 in and check them manually.

Comment: Hello, if the plugin creates 301 redirections, how comes there are still 24k errors in the search console ? Thank you.

Comment: So, any idea ? It still shows 26k "unfound links" but your plugin is set-up and running.